# Can ping but not wget between Docker containers

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose to set up a NextJS-app that fetches data from the Wordpress REST-API running in separate containers.

Problem is, I get `ECONNREFUSED` when I try to fetch or WGET the wordpress-container http://wordpress:8000 from the NextJS-container. I can ping wordpress:8000 without any problems.

If I use Postman or try to fetch the REST-API from another host (i.e. not the machine running docker-compose) using the public ip, it works perfectly.

I'm suspecting some docker configuration issue, but I'm quite lost as the pinging works but not the wget.

Anyone with an idea on what the culprit could be?

**My docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '2'
  services:
  db:
   image: mysql:5.7
   volumes:
     - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
   restart: always
   environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ***REMOVED***
     MYSQL_DATABASE: ***REMOVED***
     MYSQL_USER: ***REMOVED***
     MYSQL_PASSWORD: ***REMOVED***
   networks:
     - back
   wordpress:
     depends_on:
     - db
     image: wordpress:latest
   volumes:
     - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content 
   ports:
     - "8000:80"
   restart: always
   environment:
     WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
     WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
     WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ***REMOVED****
   networks:
     - back
   phpmyadmin:
   depends_on:
     - db
   image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
   restart: always
   ports: 
     - 8080:80
   environment:
     PMA_HOST: db
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ***REMOVED***
   networks:
     - back
   next-app:
     depends_on:
       - wordpress
   build:
     context: ./next-app
     dockerfile: Dockerfile
   volumes:
     - './next-app:/usr/src/app'
     - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
   ports:
     - '80:3000'
   networks:
     - back
 express-server:
   build:
   context: ./express-server
   dockerfile: Dockerfile
   ports:
     - '3001:3001'
networks:
   back:
   driver: bridge
volumes:
   db_data:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From inside the NextJS-container you need to use port `80`. Port `8000` it's from your (host) machine. So use http://wordpress:80 from inside the docker containers.

---

```
   ports:
     - "8000:80"
```

In you docker-compose file just says: "Map my local (host machine) port `8000` to containers ports `80`", but inside the docker network, it's still port `80`

You can ping, because ping doesn't use ports. Ports that we are talking about are TCP/UDP ports, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking). But ping uses ICMP (Internet Control Message Protocol), which doesn't use ports at all, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)

Comment: I had two containers with container port 80 and changed the phpmyadmin port to 81. Then I did the fetch to wordpress:80 and it works! Excellent, thanks a lot!!